# Getting rid of arc in glasses whilst making it look the bottle is full

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to create a wine bottle, but I get very unrealistic looking glass results:

[image], what I want to achieve is something like this:

[Sample wine bottle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIm-SZHKOW4),

I fail in the first stage of material. How do I get this? No matter where I light the bottle from, those arc don't go away and the bottle material is very unsatisfactory.

Here is the blend:

[image]